# Joda DateTimeFormat for year of decade

Tags: java, jodatime, date-formatting

I'd like to format a Joda LocalDateTime in the format yDDD where the "y" represents not the full year, but rather one single digit representing the year of the decade and the DDD represents the day of the year. It seems "yDDD" as a format string correctly interprets DDD as "day of the year", but instead of printing a single character for the year, prints the entire 4-digit year. How can I format a Joda LocalDateTime with just the last digit of the year?

For example, February 1, 2021 would be represented as 1032:

- `1` for year 1 in the decade
- `032` for the 32nd day of the year.

Comment: why would you need such a format? 2001-322 and 2011-322 will be formatted to 1-322 based on your explanation. It is ambiguous.

Comment: @Juvanis Yes, it is ambiguous. The reason I need it in this format is because in my industry we have to integrate against very old-fashioned APIs (think code running on mainframes). In the context, a decade's worth of unique dates is enough to be sufficiently unambiguous. This is conceptually the same as the mm-dd-yy format, which is also ambiguous, but on a per-century basis rather than per-decade.

Comment: I do not think you can do that. I expect you'll have to use `myStrangeDate = result.substring(3);`

Answer (score 2):

This is using the java date api, but it should be easily transferrable to joda:

```
@Test
public void testDateFormat() {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DDD");
    ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("formatted: " + (date.getYear() % 10) + date.format(fmt));
}
```

it produces:

```
formatted: 1050
```

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendValueReduced()

As far as I have been able to figure out, Joda-Time cannot do what you want. java.time, the modern Java date and time API that has replaced Joda-Time since Java 8, can. Through this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter ydddFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 1, 1, LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 1))
        .appendPattern("DDD")
        .toFormatter();
```

To demonstrate:

```
    LocalDate sampleDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY, 1);
    String formattedDate = sampleDate.format(ydddFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Output:

> 1032

The `appendValueReduced` method is particularly for printing and parsing 2-digit years, but there’s no reason why we can’t use it for a 1-digit year too. Just pass 1 for both `width` and `maxWidth` for a fixed-width 1-digit year field.

The last argument to `appendValueReduced`, the `LocalDate` in my code, is a base date for interpreting a 1-digit year when parsing. For formatting it is ignored, but it’s still required to be there.

### Joda-Time and String.format()

If your date is necessarily from Joda-Time and you’re not upgrading right now, you need to use other means than Joda-Time when formatting (like the other answers do too). My suggestion for a simple solution would be to go all-in on `String.format()`:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = new LocalDateTime(2021, 2, 1, 23, 45);
    String ydddString = String.format(Locale.US, "%01d%03d",
            dateTime.getYear() % 10, dateTime.getDayOfYear());
    assert ydddString.length() == 4 : ydddString;
    System.out.println(ydddString);
```

> 1032

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode. Its creator, Stephen Colebourne, went on to create its replacement, the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

I did not find a way to do what you want using only a formatter object. However, Ole V.V. did find a way in [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66283119/642706). I recommend that solution.

In my approach, write a method to do some string manipulation, or use the math shown in [Answer by Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66282582/642706).

```
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 1 , 1 ) ;
    String yyyy = Integer.toString( ld.getYear() ) ;  // Get the number of the year as text.
    String y = yyyy.substring( yyyy.length() - 1 ) ;  // Pull last character of that year-as-text to get single-digit year of decade.
 
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "DDD" ) ;  // Get day-of-year, 1-365 or 1-366. 
    String output = y + ld.format( f ) ;

    System.out.println( output ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/S0Stix).

> 1001

## ISO 8601

I would recommend sticking with the standard format defined in [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Ordinal_dates): Four-digit year, hyphen, three-digit day-of-year.

So, 2021-01-01 is `2021-001`.

```
LocalDate.now().format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ORDINAL_DATE )
```

Comment: I obviously agree in migrating to java.time if possible. With java.time there is a way to use a formatter only, shown in my answer. Also on this point there was an improvement from Joda-Time.